# Privacy for lower level room

Tags: windows

I have a quad level home. The family room windows are pretty much ground level outside. If our neighbors walk by, they can pretty much see everything. Not  to mention our homes are pretty close.

We have film in the bathroom but, that seems to block a nice amount of light and obviously we get no privacy if the window is opened.

Any options available for some privacy that allow me to get some some light and air flow?

Comment: Curtains......?

Comment: Venetian blinds, set at an angle?

Comment: The moment in open the blinds or curtains, you can see everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translucent film lets a lot of light through and provides privacy as well (as long as you don't get to close to the window). There are window films with beautiful patterns and even ones that can be attached to window panes without an adhesive. (I think I'm not allowed to suggest a brand here.)

Comment: Can u suggest 2 words that could hint at a brand?

Comment: LOL. color cotton.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use light-filtering honeycomb shades.  They protects your privacy and your furniture, paintings, and walls from the negative effects of the sun’s glare.

These shades let the light in while protecting your privacy and the sun’s intensity. They have cordless option and are safe for your children and pets. Their prices are reasonable and products durable, not to mention the energy efficiency benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Privacy, light and airflow.

Sounds like a fence or dense hedge, as far from the house as possible.

Comment: That was my first thought but my property line between us is about 3 feet. Not nearly enough space.